# Averiguar si el objeto existe en arrayList y sumar su atributo si existe

Tags: java, spring-boot, arraylist

estoy intentado hacer que al importar un archivo excel a un arrayList, los objetos que tengan el "customerid" igual, se les sume su atributo "totaldeuda", por ejemplo en la siguiente lista, se repite dos veces el customerid "900.778.206-4", en la columna Total deberian de sumarse los dos valores con un total de ($1.071.000) y que solo se muestre una vez en la tabla ese "custumer ID"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la clase:

```
public class DebtFileTO {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private String customerid;
private String customernombre;
private String customeremail;
private String customerphone;
private double totaldeuda;
```

Y este es mi metodo para leer e importar el excel al arrayList:

```
@PostMapping("/importExcel")
public String mapReapExcelDatatoDB(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile reapExcelDataFile, Model model) throws IOException {
    
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(); 
    
    List<DebtFileTO> debtFileTOs = new ArrayList<DebtFileTO>();
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(reapExcelDataFile.getInputStream());
    XSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    
    for(int i=1;i<worksheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows() ;i++) {
        DebtFileTO debtFileTO = new DebtFileTO();
            
        XSSFRow row = worksheet.getRow(i);
            
        debtFileTO.setCustomerid(row.getCell(4).getStringCellValue());
        debtFileTO.setCustomernombre(row.getCell(2).getStringCellValue());
        debtFileTO.setCustomeremail(row.getCell(9).getStringCellValue());
        debtFileTO.setCustomerphone(row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
        debtFileTO.setTotaldeuda(row.getCell(8).getNumericCellValue());
        
        decimalFormat.format(debtFileTO.getTotaldeuda());
        
        debtFileTOs.add(debtFileTO);   
    }
    model.addAttribute("debtFileTOs",debtFileTOs);
    return "listEmailCampaign";
}
```

Entonces la idea es que si el "Costumer ID" existe, se vayan sumando su "totaldeuda" y si por el contrario el "Customer ID" no existe se agregue a la lista.

Answer (score 3):

Como mencionas que la idea es como que agrupar por el id de cliente se me ocurrió esto:

```
public class SumIfExists {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Stream<DebtFileTO> stream = readRecordsFromExcelFile();

    Map<String, DebtFileTO> customerMap = stream.collect(
            Collectors.toMap(
                    DebtFileTO::getCustomerid,
                    Function.identity(),
                    (DebtFileTO debtFile1, DebtFileTO debtFile2)
                    -> new DebtFileTO(debtFile1.getCustomerid(), debtFile1.getCustomernombre(), debtFile1.getCustomeremail(), debtFile1.getCustomerphone(), Double.sum(debtFile1.getTotaldeuda(), debtFile2.getTotaldeuda()))
            )
    );
    System.out.println(customerMap);

 }
}
```

Suponiendo la siguiente entrada:

```
[DebtFileTO{customerid=900.778.206-4, customernombre=Conciviles contruccion, customeremail=conciviles@construccion.com, customerphone=123,456, totaldeuda=535500.0}, DebtFileTO{customerid=900.778.206-4, customernombre=Conciviles contruccion, customeremail=conciviles@construccion.com, customerphone=123,456, totaldeuda=535500.0}, DebtFileTO{customerid=1b5097cd-8a1f-4376-b8dc-9fb7c30a284e, customernombre=Gibson, DuBuque and Welch, customeremail=alverta.pouros@hotmail.com, customerphone=1-756-185-7538, totaldeuda=2125.25}, DebtFileTO{customerid=cea03f78-a0d4-44b7-a76c-9d6b90deddf6, customernombre=Morar, Mueller and Konopelski, customeremail=fletcher.gaylord@yahoo.com, customerphone=050-934-6240, totaldeuda=2448.21}, DebtFileTO{customerid=7913a85f-d7da-4262-9648-29db319189f8, customernombre=King, Dibbert and Goldner, customeremail=shaun.mohr@yahoo.com, customerphone=908.795.4475, totaldeuda=4666.25}, DebtFileTO{customerid=cdcbe2b6-367e-40f5-b320-d14aa2a1afd0, customernombre=Christiansen LLC, customeremail=wilfredo.renner@gmail.com, customerphone=1-282-290-1358, totaldeuda=4176.82}, DebtFileTO{customerid=3f5c237f-d5dc-4bb8-9e58-29a1101b7294, customernombre=Leffler, Wiegand and Corkery, customeremail=lon.rutherford@gmail.com, customerphone=098-044-3567, totaldeuda=7157.39}, DebtFileTO{customerid=46e14d26-1f1f-4005-8b28-c9ecefb8a6de, customernombre=Mitchell, Blick and VonRueden, customeremail=bryce.johnson@yahoo.com, customerphone=(503) 197-0876, totaldeuda=7268.22}, DebtFileTO{customerid=c952e694-1fee-4abe-b16a-acda64d3387b, customernombre=Schumm-Hessel, customeremail=scottie.kiehn@hotmail.com, customerphone=1-513-247-8369, totaldeuda=5534.48}, DebtFileTO{customerid=84eb79d7-9712-4cda-918d-8aca17e59222, customernombre=Jenkins, Little and Marks, customeremail=corey.keebler@gmail.com, customerphone=1-533-727-8441, totaldeuda=6224.03}, DebtFileTO{customerid=67c57d4c-54ee-453d-b34e-be0857447c0d, customernombre=Fadel, Pfeffer and Leffler, customeremail=houston.johns@gmail.com, customerphone=357.568.9745, totaldeuda=5416.22}, DebtFileTO{customerid=3e80a346-7737-48ef-b55f-68aecbe86963, customernombre=Hyatt, Nicolas and Wolff, customeremail=britt.koelpin@yahoo.com, customerphone=084.943.6757, totaldeuda=7043.93}, DebtFileTO{customerid=3d0eb6d9-a09f-4f41-a0f2-7762e8279fd5, customernombre=Bashirian Group, customeremail=greg.roberts@gmail.com, customerphone=(573) 096-3664, totaldeuda=5217.04}, DebtFileTO{customerid=aef16c8a-65b0-4c84-94cb-72fd1a4b8faf, customernombre=VonRueden, Koepp and Pfannerstill, customeremail=amos.cremin@hotmail.com, customerphone=1-642-839-9400, totaldeuda=5052.77}]
```

en la que si te fijas tiene el elemento duplicado de ejemplo que mencionas y algunos que agregué generados aleatoriamete

La salida en consola sería algo como:

```
{7913a85f-d7da-4262-9648-29db319189f8=DebtFileTO{customerid=7913a85f-d7da-4262-9648-29db319189f8, customernombre=King, Dibbert and Goldner, customeremail=shaun.mohr@yahoo.com, customerphone=908.795.4475, totaldeuda=4666.25}, 3f5c237f-d5dc-4bb8-9e58-29a1101b7294=DebtFileTO{customerid=3f5c237f-d5dc-4bb8-9e58-29a1101b7294, customernombre=Leffler, Wiegand and Corkery, customeremail=lon.rutherford@gmail.com, customerphone=098-044-3567, totaldeuda=7157.39}, 900.778.206-4=DebtFileTO{customerid=900.778.206-4, customernombre=Conciviles contruccion, customeremail=conciviles@construccion.com, customerphone=123,456, totaldeuda=1071000.0}, 3d0eb6d9-a09f-4f41-a0f2-7762e8279fd5=DebtFileTO{customerid=3d0eb6d9-a09f-4f41-a0f2-7762e8279fd5, customernombre=Bashirian Group, customeremail=greg.roberts@gmail.com, customerphone=(573) 096-3664, totaldeuda=5217.04}, 1b5097cd-8a1f-4376-b8dc-9fb7c30a284e=DebtFileTO{customerid=1b5097cd-8a1f-4376-b8dc-9fb7c30a284e, customernombre=Gibson, DuBuque and Welch, customeremail=alverta.pouros@hotmail.com, customerphone=1-756-185-7538, totaldeuda=2125.25}, 84eb79d7-9712-4cda-918d-8aca17e59222=DebtFileTO{customerid=84eb79d7-9712-4cda-918d-8aca17e59222, customernombre=Jenkins, Little and Marks, customeremail=corey.keebler@gmail.com, customerphone=1-533-727-8441, totaldeuda=6224.03}, aef16c8a-65b0-4c84-94cb-72fd1a4b8faf=DebtFileTO{customerid=aef16c8a-65b0-4c84-94cb-72fd1a4b8faf, customernombre=VonRueden, Koepp and Pfannerstill, customeremail=amos.cremin@hotmail.com, customerphone=1-642-839-9400, totaldeuda=5052.77}, 67c57d4c-54ee-453d-b34e-be0857447c0d=DebtFileTO{customerid=67c57d4c-54ee-453d-b34e-be0857447c0d, customernombre=Fadel, Pfeffer and Leffler, customeremail=houston.johns@gmail.com, customerphone=357.568.9745, totaldeuda=5416.22}, 46e14d26-1f1f-4005-8b28-c9ecefb8a6de=DebtFileTO{customerid=46e14d26-1f1f-4005-8b28-c9ecefb8a6de, customernombre=Mitchell, Blick and VonRueden, customeremail=bryce.johnson@yahoo.com, customerphone=(503) 197-0876, totaldeuda=7268.22}, cdcbe2b6-367e-40f5-b320-d14aa2a1afd0=DebtFileTO{customerid=cdcbe2b6-367e-40f5-b320-d14aa2a1afd0, customernombre=Christiansen LLC, customeremail=wilfredo.renner@gmail.com, customerphone=1-282-290-1358, totaldeuda=4176.82}, cea03f78-a0d4-44b7-a76c-9d6b90deddf6=DebtFileTO{customerid=cea03f78-a0d4-44b7-a76c-9d6b90deddf6, customernombre=Morar, Mueller and Konopelski, customeremail=fletcher.gaylord@yahoo.com, customerphone=050-934-6240, totaldeuda=2448.21}, 3e80a346-7737-48ef-b55f-68aecbe86963=DebtFileTO{customerid=3e80a346-7737-48ef-b55f-68aecbe86963, customernombre=Hyatt, Nicolas and Wolff, customeremail=britt.koelpin@yahoo.com, customerphone=084.943.6757, totaldeuda=7043.93}, c952e694-1fee-4abe-b16a-acda64d3387b=DebtFileTO{customerid=c952e694-1fee-4abe-b16a-acda64d3387b, customernombre=Schumm-Hessel, customeremail=scottie.kiehn@hotmail.com, customerphone=1-513-247-8369, totaldeuda=5534.48}}
```

que como verás está haciendo la suma de los registros.

Si no te gusta tener ese mapa puedes sacar un iterados de los valores y mandarlos a una lista al final de este proceso.

### Explicación

El método `Collectors.toMap` en su verisón de tres parámetros recibe tres funciones:

1. Función para las claves
2. Función para los valores
3. Función de mezclado en caso de duplicados

En tu caso la primera es tu clave principal ya que es un identificador único.
La segunda es una función identidad, es decir lo que recibe de entrada lo regresa tal cual.
La tercera debe ser un operador binario ( `BinaryOperator` por si quieres leer la documentación ), recibe los dos valores duplicados y decide que hacer.

Para el algoritmo de la tercera función

1. tomamos todos los campos menos el total del primero y se los asignamos a un nuevo objeto.
2. sumamos ambas deudas
3. el resultado de 2 se lo asignamos al nuevo objeto que se va a guardar en el mapa

Y si con eso quedas medio perdido de como modificar tu código para usarlo, para refactorizar tu código y usar lo anterior digamos que empiezas por aplicar el principio S de SOLID y extraes funcionalidades comunes a métodos.

por ejemplo la creación y llenado del `DebtFileTO` en digamos el método

```
private static DebtFileTO readRecordFromExcel(XSSFRow row) {
 DebtFileTO debtFileTO = new DebtFileTO();
 debtFileTO.setCustomerid(row.getCell(4).getStringCellValue());
 debtFileTO.setCustomernombre(row.getCell(2).getStringCellValue());
 debtFileTO.setCustomeremail(row.getCell(9).getStringCellValue());
 debtFileTO.setCustomerphone(row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
 debtFileTO.setTotaldeuda(row.getCell(8).getNumericCellValue());
        
 decimalFormat.format(debtFileTO.getTotaldeuda()); // WTF esto no se guarda en ningún lado xD
 return debtFileTO;
}
```

para crear un objeto de la pestaña del Excel. Esta es una función tan matemáticamente bien expresada que se le llama función pura

y continuamos con un método que regrese un poderoso `Stream` para poder usar las bondades de Java8 que haga el resto, pero en vez de usar la lista use un Stream, del `Stream Api`.

```
private Stream<DebtFileTO> readRecordsFromExcelFile() {
 XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(reapExcelDataFile.getInputStream());
 XSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
 
 return StreamSupport.stream(
                Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(
                        worksheet.rowIterator(),
                        Spliterator.ORDERED)
                , false)
        .map(this::readRecordFromExcel);
}
```

Como habrás notado, para quitar el ciclo con índices mejor usé un iterador, y para meterlo en un stream debí de usar su hermano que va para adelante y hacia atrás el spliterador; a dicho spliterador le ponemos el parámetro `false` para que no intente usar paralelismo ( en el caso de manejo de archivos usar paralelismo es la manera más fácil de dañar el desempeño y creeme no vale la pena en este caso leer al mismo tiempo todas las pestañas del excel si quieres aclaraciones pregunta en los comentarios o haz otra pregunta para darle reputación a alguien).

después de eso para no tener un stream de hojas de excel lo mapeo con nuestra función y como me da flojera escribir los parámetros uso su referencia estática.

Estos dos métodos los acabo de hacer de memoria y en el aire así que tómalos como guía, la verdad me dió extrema flojera configurarle la dependencia que creo que es [apache-poi](/questions/tagged/apache-poi) y que no he usado desde hace un titipuchal de tiempo.

Comment: Excelente, solo una cosa que no me gusta y es la línea donde se crea un nuevo `DebtFileTO`, que se queda enorme y fea... yo añadiría un constructor a la clase que reciba como parámetro dos objetos de su misma clase y devuelva la versión ya sumada (o en un archivo de utilidades si quieres mantener la lógica fuera del *POJO*), y así poder quitar esa línea enorme del flujo que hasta (ahí era bastante bonito), dejando solo una llamada al nuevo constructor/utilidad.

Comment: @Benito-B de hecho en la pregunta no tenía ni constructor y los valores se ponían por setters... y sí... me dió flojera ponerle un builder para garatizar que cumpliera con la especificación JavaBean, pero pues tampoco voy a hacer todo yo ¿o no?.

Comment: *pero pues tampoco voy a hacer todo yo ¿o no?* -> Eso es cierto, pero con todo lo que has hecho ya...!!! Es broma hombre :), no digo que lo tengas que hacer tú, que lo haga autor de la pregunta cuando lo implemente, que así también practica un poco!